# Conjugate points on manifolds

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, causality

My question is:
Why do [conjugate points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_points) exist on globally hyperbolic manifolds, satisfying the strong energy condition?
We define M to be globally hyperbolic if it posseses a cauchy surface and a pair of points $p,q$ are said to be conjugate if there exist a Jacobi field which is not identically zero but vanishes at $p$ and $q$.
I dont see the connection there. Could someone explain it?

Comment: In a more intuitive way, you can consider the optical approximation of relativity, where the spacetime curvature roughly acts like a lens for light. The strong energy condition implies that it acts like a convex lens, producing some gravitational lensing effects. At a far enough distance, you could "focus" a family of null geodesics (light rays) into a single point, which is the conjugate point to your source.

Comment: As far as I can tell, not every globally hyperbolic manifold with the strong energy condition has conjugate points. Flat spacetime doesn't.

Comment: For me your more intuitive way doenst helped at all. I would like an explanation in the sense of general relativity.